# To what extent will (should?) Stack Overflow & co. be employer-friendly?

Tags: discussion, jobs, employer

I'm certain this idea occurred to the developers of Stack Overflow a long time ago. The potential is huge. Sure, I've got a LinkedIn profile with a few recommendations, but where's the hard evidence of my skill? Anyone can look nice on paper.

With Stack Overflow it's different. You're being rated by other people in the same field. A quick glance on your profile by a programmer-savvy person from Company X, and he could tell if your skill set would fit or not.

I'm particularly interested in this because due to my somewhat unusual "education", my age does not fit my CV and while employers in Sweden haven't raised many eyebrows, I've found it harder to be taken seriously in other countries.

I've seen hints that the sites will be extended to support some kind of employment help services. But how far will – and should – this be taken?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/958/what-will-the-future-recruiting-features-of-stack-overflow-involve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent, I am sure that you can use your SO reputation on your CV/resume, but with that comes a dangerous territory.  The reputation is not a measurement of one's skill, it is a reflection of trust from the community.  If you answer 10K questions, I would hope you have 3K reputation.  But because you've answered 10K question, does 3K really mean that much?

You may be able to highlight some specific questions that you helped solve, and show that you are resourceful enough to not get stuck on any one issue for very long because of tools like SO.  Overall, I hope that the reputation is not what employers look at if they look at SO at all.

The other side of this is they could say you spend too much time on SO and would not fit in very well with their demanding schedules...

Comment: Good points! I hope there will be more ways to determine a person's skill based on their activity on SO, like a score/stat that isn't affected by time (i.e., number of answers/questions) but by quality. But at least a technically inclined person at the company hiring can see what areas the person is most familiar with (based on tags) and look at some of their answers to determine their knowledge of the area.

Answer (score 2):

There's already the links to http://jobs.stackoverflow.com (on SO) and http://jobs.joelonsoftware.com (here), so I would expect any employer posting a job to check any applicants profile.

I think more employers will look at SO profiles as more people post their flair on blogs, LinkedIn etc., after all it's another claim you are making and any employer should verify those claims.

Plus the "I'm open to employers (not recruiters) contacting me" check box on the "prefs" tab of your profile indicates that something is in the offing.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly hope to see you on

http://careers.stackoverflow.com

:)

Where's my beloved

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/blixt ?

Comment: Awesome! I published a preliminary CV to test it out, looks nice! =)